# how to change query parameter name in Nginx

Tags: nginx

there is an api , e.g. `http://example.com/v2/series/search?token=xxx&&limit=50&offset=0&databases=WORLD`

one day  some query parameter changed , e.g. databases ==> database, and cause the request is failed

```
response code:400 message:Filter('s) `databases` is(are) not supported.
```

so how to  change query parameter name in Nginx location block?

I know how to append parameter by below way, but how to change parameter name?

```
location = /v2/series/search {
    set $args $args&foo=bar;
    proxy_pass xxx;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
if ($args ~ (^|.*&)databases=(.*)) {
    set $args $1database=$2;
}
```

Should replace the `databases` query argument name to `database` regardless of whether it is at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of the query string.